# VBA to input value in specific search box on Web Page

Tags: html, vba

I have looked on other posts before asking a question here. After many hours and no luck, I'm hoping someone can help me. I have the HTML code below in which I'm trying to insert a value in the "Integration Systems" search box.

```
    <li class="WDQO"
        role="presentation">
        <div class="WFQO WIPO">
            <label id="15$373935--uid5-formLabel"
                    for="15$373935--uid5-input"
                    data-automation-id="formLabel">Integration Event Status</label>
            <div class="WHQO wd-68ba40b3-10ce-4646-87a0-022333ac3bc4"
                aria-hidden="true">Integration Event Status</div>
        </div>
        <div class="WIQO"
            id="15$373935"
            data-automation-id="decorationWrapper">
                <input width="280" tabindex="0" class="css-11ftvoe-InputContainer ejruka1" id="15$373935--uid5-input"
                        aria-disabled="false" aria-invalid="false" aria-describedby="d2ef839e-8cb5-45d4-bd03-16cc3991a828"
                        aria-labelledby="15$373935--uid5-formLabel" dir="ltr" placeholder="Search" value="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="WDQO"
        role="presentation">
        <div class="WFQO WIPO">
            <label id="15$385114--uid4-formLabel"
                    for="15$385114--uid4-input"
                    data-automation-id="formLabel">Integration Systems</label>
            <div class="WHQO wd-68ba40b3-10ce-4646-87a0-022333ac3bc4"
                aria-hidden="true">Integration Systems</div>
        </div>
        <div class="WIQO"
            id="15$385114"
            data-automation-id="decorationWrapper">
            <input width="280" tabindex="0" class="css-ptbla1-InputContainer ejruka1" id="15$385114--uid4-input"
                    aria-disabled="false" aria-invalid="false" aria-describedby="91766dc4-524e-4020-8cc6-8fc6a52b189f"
                    aria-labelledby="15$385114--uid4-formLabel" dir="ltr" placeholder="Search" value="" />
        </div>
    </li>
```

Below is my VBA code. I'm trying to loop through to get the search box of "Integration Systems", but I'm not sure how to get this working properly. I can't even get the VBA code to work to input a value of "TEST". Can someone help or lead me in the right direction?

```
    Function GetIE() As Object

      Dim ShellApp As Object, ShellWindows As Object
      Dim IEObject As Object
      Dim inputField As Object, e As Object, elements As Object, inputFields As Object

    'Start code to open current Internet Explorer
                Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
                Set ShellWindows = ShellApp.Windows()
                Dim item As Object
                On Error GoTo 0
                Dim sName As String

                   For Each ObjWind In ShellWindows
                    'On Error Resume Next
                     If (Not ObjWind Is Nothing) Then
                        sName = ObjWind.Name
                         If sName = "Internet Explorer" Then
                            Set IEObject = ObjWind
                            Exit For  'No need to continue....
                         End If
                     End If

                    Next

                If IEObject Is Nothing Then Set IEObject = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    'End code to open current Internet Explorer

    'Now to attempt to input data in search box for Integration Systems. This doesn't work.
    'With IEObject.document
    '    Set elements = .getElementsByTagName("div")
    '    For Each e In elements
    '        If (e.IEObject.getElementsById("15$385114--uid30-input").Value = "TEST" Then
    '            e.Click
    '            Exit For
    '        End If
    '    Next e
    'End With

    'Second option to use the ID instead of specific search box with Integration Systems. This doesn't work.
        IEObject.getElementsById("15$385114--uid30-input").Value = "TEST"
        
     Set ShellApp = Nothing
     Set GetIE = IEObject
    End Function
```

Comment: Is page a frameset?

Comment: Hi @LS_ᴅᴇᴠ, I don't know much about HTML, but after doing some research, I think the page is a frameset. Let me know if I need to search for anything on  webpage or if I should take a screenshot.

Comment: You are probably missing `IEObject.Navigate "http://..."`!